# Let $F$ a vector field defined by $F=(P,Q,R)$. find a form for: $rotF=((\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z})$,

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F$ a vector field defined by $F=(P,Q,R)$. Find a form for:

$$\operatorname{rot}F=\Biggl(\biggl(\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}\biggr),\biggl(\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}\biggr),\biggl(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\biggr)\Biggr)$$

In the next cases:

$(a)\ F(x,y,z)=(y^2,xy,xz)$

$(b)\ F(x,y,z)=(y-z,yz,-xz)$

I don't have idea of how to solve this exercise. Can someone help me or give me a hint?

Comment: Can you not just apply the formula you were given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case $P(x,y,z) = y^2, Q(x,y,z) = xy, R(x,y,z) = xz$. You just need to compute the partial derivatives required by the formula.

The second case is analogous. There is nothing more than this.

Comment: oh, now i understand. Thanks Gibbs!